# Which Active Directory Attribute(s) Map to Groups the User is a Member of

Tags: active-directory, okta, active-directory-group

Context:  Trying to figure out which Active Directory attributes I need to import into Okta for my custom application.

Is there an Active Directory (AD) attribute that maps to the group names of groups that the user is a part of?  Tried  searching for resources online, the Microsoft Docs have a list of (some) attributes, but there are no human friendly descriptions of what the attributes actually are.

Is there better documentation of AD attributes somewhere?  Also the list of AD attributes Okta imports from AD has AD attributes not on Microsoft's Docs.

Active Directory Attributes:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675090%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I've no experience of Okta, but, from AD point of view, please check if there is any attribute/property named `Group Membership / memberOf`.

Comment: Hi, so these are the AD attributes with "group" in their name:  `msDS-OIDToGroupLinkBl`, `tokenGroupsGlobalAndUniversal`, `groupMembershipSAM`, `groupPriority`, `groupsToIgnore`, `tokenGroupsNoGCAcceptable`, `tokenGroups`, `primaryGroupID`.  I've tried inspecting these values of my AD users by writing custom claims for my ID token (OIDC) and using Okta's Dashboard's ID Token preview I've tried inspecting these values, but they either show as blank or Okta throws an error.

Comment: Please check the attribute `memberOf` in AD for any user, it'd exist. Corresponding to this, I guess there should be something similar in Okta to fetch group membership detail for any user.

Comment: Gotcha, I found the `memberOf` attribute! After reading the docs I'm very optimistic that this is what I'm looking for.  Having difficulty getting Okta to fetch this attribute from my AD, but if that works I'll let you know.  Thanks!!